# Google Sheets - Delete values of range if I have 0 in values of certain column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to remove values in column B and C if in the column B I have cells with value 0.

I have tried this based on other code on this forum, with the method push to fill a empty range. The problem is when I clearContent on both arrays (values of B and C) it cleans all my values even if they have values different from zero.

I try to search the error with fontsize my second range(values of C) and it works.

My code is :

```js
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues(); 
  var range = []; 
  var rangeC= []; 
  data.forEach(function(e, i){ 
    if (e[0] == "0"){  
      range.push("B" + (i + 1)); 
      rangeC.push("C" + (i + 1)); 
    }
  });
  sheet.getRangeList(range).clearContent();
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeC).clearContent();
```

Comment: I think that your script works for clearing the searched rows of columns "B" and "C" when the column "B" is `0`. So, I would like to correctly understand about your current issue. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I try to search the error with fontsize my second range(values of C) and it works.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i would like to clear values of range B:C when values in B=0 clear that cell and de cell attached to it in the column C, whith my code when i used clear content for both Ranges it removes all the values even if they are diferent to 0, thats why i tried to use Fontsize with the range C and next supreme the fontsized values.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that 2 answers have already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following edited code for you, i think is much better than using `push` function to clear a content, although I did not use `clearContent` in this case, `===` to prevent clear range if empty:

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange('B:D');
  var data = range.getValues(); 
 
  data.forEach(function(row){  
    if (row[0] === 0){
      row[0] ='';
      row[1] ='';
    }  
  });
 range.setValues(data)
}
```

Comment: I tried with you code attaching other blank space for the values of C but it didn´t work with that column

Comment: I didn't aware that you are trying to clear col b and c based on col b value if is zero, let me try workout a solution

Comment: Thanks a lot Kin Siang, my function cleans two columns of data (B and C) , column"C" contains a value entered by the user. Column "B" has a formula that looks for the value in C and writes a integer in column B. I try with your code adding a method to keep the formulas on the cells but i cannot erase the values on "C"

Comment: I have modified the code as per your statement, it should be work as per your expectation :)

Comment: Thanks, it really works succesfully, thanks a lot , i'll practice my programming skills to help other people like you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange('B:C');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas=range.getFormulas();


   data.forEach(function(row, index){    
   //console.log('Index:'+ index + 'row' + row);
    row.forEach(function(amount,index1,array){
  //console.log('Row: ' + array);
    var index2=row.slice(0,1);
    if (row[0] == 0 && row[1]>0){
   
     sheet.getRange(row).clear({commentsOnly: true});

    //console.log('Row after: ' + row)
    //data[index][index1] = "";
    //console.log(data)
        }
        });
      });

   range.setFormulas(formulas)
   //range.setValues(data)
    }
```